# Xilinx ISE fails to use std_logic_1164

Tags: std, vhdl, xilinx

I have Xilinx ISE 13.1 installed on an ACER laptop with Win7 (64bit).

After installing the software (WebPACK version) I created an empty VHDL module and ran "check syntax". The process failed with the following errors:

> Error:HDLParsers:3016 - "C:/Users/..." Library unit standard required for unit std_logic_1164 does not exist in library std.

and

> Error:HDLParsers:3046 - "C:/Users/..." Line 21. Library unit STD_LOGIC_1164 is not available in library IEEE.

This also occurs if I run synthesize.

Googling solutions hasn't been very effective and the hyperlink for the error in ISE leads to a "page not found" result from the Xilinx website.

If anyone can shed any light on this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The tool cannot find the default libraries (STD and IEEE). Either the installation is messed up big time, or you did something strange creating the module. Perhaps try to create a new empty project?

Comment: Yeah that is on a new empty project. Happens every time regardless of what sort of source file I create. I tried reinstalling and the same error occurred :(

Comment: Is there a hyphen in the path to the Xilinx install?

Comment: @sharth Interesting question. Perhaps a space will cause problems too?

Comment: @Philippe: on linux, I had an issue where ISE could not open the project.xise file unless the path did not have a hyphen in it. Perhaps under windows it fails later. (As an aside, why a hyphen would matter, is a mystery to me)

Answer (score 1):

make sure you install Xilin in a directory that does not contain space, some of Xilinx scripts will not work if your path contains a space.

It is a common mistake and should have been taken care of the installation SW, but Xilinx doesn't seem to be able to fix it after all these years.

Try to re-install the SW, make sure you install all your libraries and programs on the C:\ or what ever root directory you have and absolutely not under "program files" or "My Document" or something like that.